# access vba rgb function causes overflow

Tags: vba, integer-overflow

Access VBA is giving me a runtime overflow error on the following subroutine invoked from an event procedure.

```
Private Sub TboThreat_Evaluate()
  
    Dim i, red, orange, yellow As Integer

    red = RGB(244, 90, 90)
    orange = RGB(248, 192, 90)
    yellow = RGB(242, 237, 14)
    
End Sub
```

red and orange are assigned correctly and yellow causes an overflow.  Why?  it makes no sense.  I should have 12 bits of leading zeros.  If I execute the yellow statement in the immediate window it works fine.  In the event procedure the first two execute and yellow fails.  If I reorder them yellow still fails.

It is easy enough to work around this but I'd really like to know why VBA has trouble doing simple bit manipulations.

Comment: 1) `Dim i, red, orange, yellow As Integer` means `i`, `red`, `orange` are `Variant`. You have to explicitly declare variable with their variable type. change `Integer` to `Long`, `RGB` returns a [Long](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rgb-function). So your declaration would be `Dim red As Long, orange as Long, yellow As Long` (not sure what `i` is for)

Comment: @RaymondWu, Thanks for your help. That does fix it.  I did eventually realize that my declarations were wrong.  Am I allowed to rant about how brain damaged VBA is? I'm a newbie to VBA but I've been writing C & Java for years. One would think that the compiler would have generated a syntax error.  One might even have hoped that it would do an appropriate type conversion on function arguments.  That's a little advanced but hey, it's 2021, not 1985.

Comment: @RaymondWu, Thanks for your help. That does fix it.  I did eventually realize that my declarations were wrong. Your explanation helped me understand how wrong they were.  [More ranting about VBA]. VBA has all the grace of a simple language designed to run on 8 bit microprocessors in 1964 grafted to an elephantine object model.  It has all the charm and grace of metastatic brain cancer.

Comment: Your declaration is legal in VBA but it's not declared the same way you thought it is.